# Can I use Firebase Cloud Messaging for mobile browser?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've been using Firebase Cloud Messaging for desktop browser via the FCM JavaScript API.

Does anyone know if this can be used for mobile browsers?

Been running into difficulties when trying to get the mobile browser token so that specific browsers can be targeted.

Comment: That depends on the specific browser. I regularly use FCM.js in Chrome on Android without problems. But on iOS it won't work, due to the lack of support for service workers on the platform. If you're having trouble making it work, please share the [minimal code that is needed to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).